# Número límite de consulta de registros de salida con relación

Tags: sql, postgresql

saludos estoy intendado hacer un query el cual me devuelva registros diferentes, pero me encuentro con un problema en cuanto a la relación ya que me trae la cantidad de registros que tenga esa relacion, por ejemplo tengo un eventoPadre con varias localidades, hay dos tablas "eventos" y "eventos_localidades", en la tabla de eventos esta el id del evento con el cual se relacionan las localidades asociadas a ese evento, al hacer le query me trae por ejemplo si tengo 2 localidades de ese evento, me trae 2 registros con el mismo idEvento, pero yo necesito que me traiga solo 1, ya llevo mucho timepo intentando en el query pero no me funciona, muchas gracias.

este es el query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ev.id as idEvento,
        cat.nemonico as tipoEvento,
        ev.fecha_registro as ocurrencia,
        ev.estado as estado,
        ev.alto_impacto as altoImpacto,
        ev.calificacion as calificacion,
        ev.es_macroevento as esMacroevento,
        evloc.tipo_localidad as tipolocalidad,
        evloc.id_localidad as idLocalidad,
        pa.codigo as codigoParroquia,
        pa.nombre as nombreParroquia,
        ca.nombre as nombreCanton,
        pr.nombre as nombreProvincia
FROM tbl_evento_peligroso ev
JOIN tbl_evento_peligroso_localidad evloc
    ON ev.id = evloc.id_evento_peligroso
JOIN cat_enumerado cat 
    ON ev.enum_tipo_evento = cat.id
JOIN tbl_parroquia pa
    ON pa.id = evloc.id_localidad
JOIN tbl_canton ca
    ON ca.id = pa.id_canton
JOIN tbl_provincia pr
    ON pr.id = ca.id_provincia
WHERE ev.fecha_registro
BETWEEN '2023-01-24 00:00:00'
AND '2023-02-11 23:59:59'
AND evloc.estado = 'A'
AND evloc.tipo_localidad = 'PA';
```

esto me retorna
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TABLA EVENTO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TABLA EVENTOS LOCALIDADES
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ayudaría que compartieras el contenido de las tablas, quizás con un dump si no tiene datos sensibles, quizás algunos de las otras columnas que no muestras en la salida tienen campos diferentes y por eso el `distinct` te está retornando dos filas para ese evento, pero sin verlo no se puede saber.

Comment: Añadí los demas campos que me retorna el query, como mencionas si tienen campos con valores diferentes, la cosa es que necesito que solo me retorne uno indiferemetemente cual sean sus valores, solo necesito que me retorne un unico idEvento

Comment: Cuáles son las columnas que dan distintas, l oque tendrías que hacer es sacar esas que pueden ser distintas del select, o si se tiene que hacer una operación de agregación con ellas, hacerla y hacer un group by con alas que son iguales.

Comment: Si tienen distintos valores para esas columnas que querés retornar, como definís cuál de esos valores distintos vas a devolver en esa fila? De eso depende la respuesta a tu pregunta para determinar el sql que hace lo que quieras